# Liquid adding red boxes around html rendering

Tags: css, jekyll, liquid, angular

I am trying to render some Angular2 code using Jekyll and Liquid. Here's what I start with

```
{% highlight html %}
<button (click)="action('dec')">Decrement</button>
<span>{% raw %}{{count}}{% endraw %}</span>
<button (click)="action('inc')">Increment</button>
{% endhighlight %}
```

And this is what I get

[image]

The red squares have been added automatically. How do I remove them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `_sass/_syntax-highlighting.scss` remove styles for the `.err` class

```
.err   {} // Error
```